# Judaism perspective on Islam that resonate with the values of monotheism

Tags: islam, judaism

From a Jewish standpoint, how do the beliefs and practices of Islam resonate with the values of monotheism and prophethood that are central to the Abrahamic traditions?

Comment: They're very similar, though "which particular prophet got the final say-so?" has a different answer. You'll see many questions here about this; for instance, for a Jew to practice Islam would be considered *heresy*, but not *idolatry*.

Comment: Wonder why it's closed when asking for Jewish standpoint

Comment: because questions about comparative religion are off-topic on Mi Yodeya

Comment: Its not comparative religion either just asks Judaism perspective of Islam

Comment: It's clumsily phrased right now. "How does Judaism view Islam?" On-topic. "Resonate ... central to Abrahamic" ... kind of a leading question there, and as soon as you say "Abrahamic faiths", you're talking comparative religion.

Comment: Yes it's on topic, it asks how Judaism views  the connection to Abrahamic faith

Comment: You're asking "how does Judaism view the fact that billion people now follow a religion that uses a very similar, "Abrahamic", vocabulary?" (It's still not Judaism, still not okay for Jews, still can't claim to supersede Judaism.) A mild answer would be "it's a nice thing, as a lot of people aren't cut out to be Jews, but this is getting them on a good track." The fuller answer is in Maimonides' Code, Laws of Kings and their Wars, 11:7--9. https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Kings_and_Wars.11.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he

Comment: "Nevertheless, the intent of the Creator of the world is not within the power of man to comprehend, for His ways are not our ways, nor are His thoughts, our thoughts. Ultimately, all the deeds of Jesus of Nazareth and that Ishmaelite who arose after him [i.e. Mohammed] will only serve to prepare the way for Mashiach's coming and the improvement of the entire world, motivating the nations to serve God together as Tzephaniah 3:9 states: 'I will transform the peoples to a purer language that they all will call upon the name of God and serve Him with one purpose.'" - Maimonides Kings 11:7